# How to pass an object type to constructor as argument and cast a variable to it (JAVA)?

Tags: java

I have a class that accepts a `ArrayList<?>` as a constructor argument:

```
public class Test {

    public Test (ArrayList<?> data) {

    }
}
```

I want to cast `data` to `ArrayList<Type>`, and pass `Type` to constructor as an argument, something like this :

```
public class Test {

    public Test (ArrayList<?> data, Class type) {
        ArrayList<Type> newData = (ArrayList<type>) data;
    }
}
```

How can i do this in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use a generic parameter, to get the class pointed by the `Class` instance

```
public <T> Test(ArrayList<?> data, Class<T> type) {
    ArrayList<T> newData = (ArrayList<T>) data;
}
```

But this is not safe as you just assume every object fits the class, you'd better cast every object one by one

```
public <T> Test(ArrayList<?> data, Class<T> type) {
    ArrayList<T> newData = data.stream().map(o -> (T) o).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

---

Multiple classes

```
public <T, U> Test(ArrayList<?> data1, Class<T> type1, ArrayList<?> data2, Class<U> type2) {
    ArrayList<T> newData1 = data1.stream().map(o -> (T) o).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    ArrayList<U> newData2 = data2.stream().map(o -> (U) o).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

---

Instanciate an object from a `Class<T> type`

```
T item = type.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

Comment: Thank for your response. I have two more questions: 1. why 1st approach is not safe? 2. what about if i want to pass 2 class types as argument to constructor?

Comment: 3. How can i create a new object from that type: Type myType = new Type();